# How to print out the unique values of a PHP array?

Tags: php

### Details

- I have a list of my country in an array called `$country`
- When I do `dd($country);` I see this

  [image]
- I want to print out all country name of that array ( unique value only )
- can someone show me how to print that ?

### Here is what I've tried

I tried `echo (array_unique(array_values($country)));`

But I got an error

```
ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN) 
Array to string conversion
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I have my array from `$countries[$k] = $v['hq_country']['name'];`

Printing them out, I just need to do this

```
foreach(array_unique($countries) as $country){ 

echo $country ;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't `echo` an array.  It's not a string.

```
// There's no need to use array_values
$uniqueValues = array_unique($continent);

foreach($uniqueValues as $country){
    echo $country, '<br>';
}
```

Comment: You also don't need the call to array_values()

Comment: How do I print a country name ?

Comment: @evoque2015: Loop over the array and print them out.

Comment: Hey guys, now I got `Illegal string offset 'hq_country'` When I do `foreach($countries as $country){ ?>
<?php echo $country['hq_country']['name'] ?>
<?php } ?>`

Comment: @evoque2015: Why are you adding `['hq_country']['name']`?  Where are you getting that from?  You have an array of strings.  `$country` is a string.

Comment: I am so noob. I got it now.